# Splitting a number not seperated by anything using split() - java

Tags: java, split, numbers

I'm assuming this is a easy thing to answer, how would I split a number 20120101 for example, using the split() method in java to get 2012, 01, 01... I would know how to do it if it was separated by commas, or periods, but how do you do it when its not separated by anything?

Comment: Why not use substring?

Comment: Based on you example, you could use `SimpleDateFormat` to generate a `Date` object and extract the values that way.

Comment: Trying to use `split(...)` for this would be like trying to use a banana as a hammer. Sure, you might eventually get it to kind of sort of work, in a way, but it would be painful and the results not very reliable. Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: Well the assignment is based off of the split method, so I wanted to try and use that, but I could use substring if it came down to it.

Comment: It CAN be done with split; but I can't see why anybody would do so.

Comment: I knew there was a easier way of doing it, I just wanted to see how it would be done using split.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how would I split a number 20120101 for example, using the split()
>   method in java to get 2012, 01, 01...

You wouldn't; `split` is generally for text with explicit delimiters, which yours does not have (you could, see other answers, but it's not the best tool for the job). You have options:

- Use [`String.substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) to pull out substrings at specific positions. For example:

  ```
  String m = "20120101".substring(4, 6);
  ```
- Use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse the date. For example:

  ```
  Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse("20120101");
  ```
- Use math (although semantically not really appropriate given that your input is supposed to be a date). For example:

  ```
  int number = Integer.parseInt("20120101");
  int y = number / 10000;
  int m = (number / 100) % 100;
  int d = number % 100;
  ```

---

Edit:

The answer above is serious and well-meaning. The answer below is purely fun nonsense.

*Hovercraft Full Of Eels* showed how a regex can be used with `split()`.

Somewhat off topic, here are some other totally inappropriate and ugly solutions, for no real reason (I'm not going to post a regex unless I come up with a particularly nasty one):

Using `StringReader`:

```
    StringReader reader = new StringReader("20120101");
    String y, m, d;
    char buffer[];

    buffer = new char[4];
    reader.read(buffer);
    y = new String(buffer);        
    buffer = new char[2];
    reader.read(buffer);
    m = new String(buffer);
    reader.read(buffer);
    d = new String(buffer);
```

Or an *extremely convenient* solution using a modified `StringReader` to insert spaces and a `StreamTokenizer` to split the tokens:

```
    StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(new StringReader("20120101") {
        private int position = 0;
        @Override public int read () throws IOException {
            switch (++ position) {
            case 5:
            case 8:
                return ' ';
            default:
                return super.read();
            }
        }
        @Override public int read (char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            for (int n = off; n < off + len; ++ n)
                cbuf[n] = (char)read();
            return len;
        }
        @Override public boolean markSupported () {
            return false;
        }
        @Override public void reset () throws IOException {
            position = 0;
            super.reset();
        }
    });

    st.resetSyntax();
    st.wordChars('0', '9');
    st.whitespaceChars(' ', ' ');
    st.nextToken();
    String y = st.sval;
    st.nextToken();
    String m = st.sval;
    st.nextToken();
    String d = st.sval;
```

I suppose you could also write a program that read from stdin, inserted commas at appropriate places, then printed the results. You could then pipe your string to that program, read the output (using `Process`), and `split()` that. If `Process` is too straightforward, you could load the classes for that program dynamically with the class loader, then use reflection to invoke `main` after redirecting your stdin and stdout accordingly.

Comment: Why would it be better?  But I agree, it seems broken.

Comment: No, never use an ugly regex when a decent debuggable and extensible solution exists. 1+

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
String date = "20120101";

String year = date.substring(0, 4);
String month = date.substring(4, 6);
String day = date.substring(6, 8);
```

Or use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`:

```
String date = "20120101";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
try {
    cal.setTime(df.parse(date));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    // Could not parse date.
    // Break execution.
}
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Comment: this worked just fine, thank you!. instead of putting it into a string, I parsed it as a integer right away.

Comment: You parsed it as an integer?  Did you test it where one of the segments was 08 or 09?  There may be a problem there.

Comment: I dont see how it would create a problem??... as long as its in the format 20120101 I dont know how it would cause a problem

Answer (score 2):

As I said in comment, trying to use split(...) for this would be like trying to use a banana as a hammer. Sure, you might eventually get it to kind of sort of work, in a way, but it would be painful and the results not very reliable. Use the right tool for the job.

So here is one example of an ugly as h3ll `split(...)`, posted just for grins:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class DumbSplit {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String dateStr = "20120101";

      String bananaAsHammer = "(?<=.{4}).*(?=.{4})|(?<=.{6}).*(?=.{2})";
      String[] tokens = dateStr.split(bananaAsHammer);

      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));
   }
}
```

Comment: I was working on this too. Then I stopped, because surely somebody with more dedication than me would work it out and post it. Lo and behold...

Comment: @JasonC: I'm sure there are even better and uglier solutions. So yeah, go ahead and share if you've got.

Comment: oh jeez, I would have never gotten this, thank you for showing me this!! haha

Comment: I've updated my answer with a straightforward and appropriate solution using a `StringReader` and `StreamTokenizer`.